# REST API Checking if an address is confirmed

Tags: rest, paypal

We're trying to come up with an integration plan for PayPal for a website of ours but we're trying to ensure we are covered by *PayPal's Seller Protection Service*. Part of being able to ensure we're covered is only selling orders shipped to confirmed addresses.

The problem I'm having is the API doesn't seem to tell us if an address is confirmed or not. This is the result I get from the sandbox while testing:

[image: Problem]

The status is supposed to be [according to the API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#common-payments-objects) either `CONFIRMED` or `UNCONFIRMED` but it's coming back null.

We need to be able to ensure the address is confirmed **or** that the order is *fully eligible* for seller protection before sending the `Execute` Call on the payment.

How are we supposed to go about this?

Comment: Any solution? I am seeing the same thing, null rather than unconfirmed or confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my last correspondence with PayPal (Oct 2015) the answer was that the REST API is "new" and does not operate at feature parity with the older APIs. The concept of "Confirmed Addresses" isn't currently provided through the REST API.

They mentioned that this may come in the future but have no timeline available.

We ended up scrapping the REST API and going back to Express Checkout unfortunately.